# Segmentation fault on linux (gcc)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, valgrind

I am debugging a numerical program. It works well on Windows (Visual Studio compiler), giving the correct results.

Unfortunately on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 x64) with gcc the program is giving segmentation fault after some part of computations (I am getting part of results).

I tried to use Valgrind to debug it, and to get a place where I may expect the error.

The results are:

```
==19565== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==19565== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==19565== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==19565== Command: ./a.out
==19565==
==19565== Invalid read of size 8
==19565==    at 0x402E50: MAXN(double, int, double, int*, double*,
int, double*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*, double, double*,
int*, double) (in /home/muniek/Desktop/c_code/a.out)
==19565==    by 0x401991: main (in /home/muniek/Desktop/c_code/a.out)
==19565==  Address 0x54f0958 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==19565==
==19565== Invalid read of size 8
==19565==    at 0x402E65: MAXN(double, int, double, int*, double*,
int, double*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*, double, double*,
int*, double) (in /home/muniek/Desktop/c_code/a.out)
==19565==    by 0x401991: main (in /home/muniek/Desktop/c_code/a.out)
==19565==  Address 0x54f0950 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==19565==
==19565== Invalid read of size 8
==19565==    at 0x402E85: MAXN(double, int, double, int*, double*,
int, double*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*, double, double*,
int*, double) (in /home/muniek/Desktop/c_code/a.out)
==19565==    by 0x401991: main (in /home/muniek/Desktop/c_code/a.out)
==19565==  Address 0x54f0958 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==19565==
==19565== Invalid read of size 8
==19565==    at 0x402E9A: MAXN(double, int, double, int*, double*,
int, double*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*, double, double*,
int*, double) (in /home/muniek/Desktop/c_code/a.out)
==19565==    by 0x401991: main (in /home/muniek/Desktop/c_code/a.out)
==19565==  Address 0x54f0960 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==19565==
==19565== Invalid read of size 8
==19565==    at 0x402D82: MAXN(double, int, double, int*, double*,
int, double*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*, double, double*,
int*, double) (in /home/muniek/Desktop/c_code/a.out)
==19565==    by 0x401991: main (in /home/muniek/Desktop/c_code/a.out)
==19565==  Address 0x54f0978 is 8 bytes before a block of size 1,696 alloc'd
==19565==    at 0x4C29DB4: calloc (in
/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19565==    by 0x404CC0: dvector(int, int) (in
/home/muniek/Desktop/c_code/a.out)
==19565==    by 0x400A62: main (in /home/muniek/Desktop/c_code/a.out)
==19565==
==19565==
==19565== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19565==     in use at exit: 1,704 bytes in 3 blocks
==19565==   total heap usage: 1,228,705 allocs, 1,228,702 frees,
9,826,265,416 bytes allocated
==19565==
==19565== 568 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 3
==19565==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in
/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19565==    by 0x519D20A: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:76)
==19565==    by 0x401100: main (in /home/muniek/Desktop/c_code/a.out)
==19565==
==19565== 568 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 3
==19565==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in
/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19565==    by 0x519D20A: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:76)
==19565==    by 0x401116: main (in /home/muniek/Desktop/c_code/a.out)
==19565==
==19565== 568 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 3
==19565==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in
/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19565==    by 0x519D20A: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:76)
==19565==    by 0x40112C: main (in /home/muniek/Desktop/c_code/a.out)
==19565==
==19565== LEAK SUMMARY:
==19565==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19565==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19565==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19565==    still reachable: 1,704 bytes in 3 blocks
==19565==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19565==
==19565== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==19565== ERROR SUMMARY: 2664 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

I got it that there is some problem in MAXN function (am I right?).

```
void MAXN (double AMP, int ix, double DX, int *NST, double* ETE, int SP, double* C0, double* X0, double* CR, double* XC, int *N0, int *NC, double T,
  double *T0, int* GPC, double PER)
{
  double XCC, PFIX, TN;
  int SX0, ST, FN, N;

  ST = NINT((0.5/DX)+1);
  FN = NINT((1.0/DX)+1);

  PFIX = 3.0*PER/4.0;
  TN = T;
  SX0 = NINT((X0[*NST]/DX)+1);

  if (SX0 > SP+5)
    (*NST)++;

  //checks for new wave crests entering the computational domain
  for (int i = ST; i <= FN; i++)
  {
    if ((ETE[i] > ETE[i-1]) && (ETE[i] > ETE[i+1]) && (ETE[i] > 0) && (ETE[i] > (AMP/4.0)))
    {
      XCC = double((i-1)*DX);
      if ((XCC < (X0[*NC]-DX)) && ((TN-*T0) > PFIX))
      {
        *NC = *N0 + 1;
        XC[*NC] = XCC;
        CR[*NC] = ETE[i];
        *T0 =T;
         goto stop;
      }
    }
  }
  stop://label 2 continue

  //tracks existing wave crests within the computational domain
  for (int j = *NST; j <= *NC; j++)
  {
    N = NINT((X0[j]/DX)+1);
    int NCC = 0;

    for (int i = (N - 1); i <= (N + ST); i++)
    {
      if ((ETE[i] > ETE[i-1]) && (ETE[i] > ETE[i+1]) && (ETE[i] > 0))
      {
        NCC++;
        CR[j] = ETE[i];
        XC[j] = double((i-1)*DX);
      }

      if (NCC == 0)
      {
        for (int k = N-10; k <= N+10; k++)
        {
          if ((ETE[k] > ETE[k-1]) && (ETE[k] > ETE[k+1]) && (ETE[k] > 0))
          {
            CR[j] = ETE[k];
            XC[j] = double((k-1)*DX);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //update wave crests and position for next step
  for (int i = *NST; i <= *NC; i++)
  {
    GPC[i] = NINT((XC[i]/DX)+1);
    X0[i] = XC[i];
    C0[i] = CR[i];
  }

  *N0 = *NC;
}
```

How I can get more precisely the place of code which causes the segfault? What part of code can do that?

Comment: It may work as expected on Windows, but you are probably still overrunning a buffer.

Comment: Well, there's two ways.  There's the lazy way, commenting out code until it stops crashing, then there's the correct way, using a debugger.  I'd recommend using a debugger to step through the code.

Comment: Also, be sure to compile your code with debugging symbols and valgrind might be able to give you line numbers instead of memory addresses.  [See this answer for info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321385/valgrind-not-showing-line-numbers-in-spite-of-g-flag-on-ubuntu-11-10-virtualbo).

Comment: @FiddlingBits could be, but on Windows it runs correctly every single time, on Linux on even once

Comment: I guess that your program accesses an element of ETE that is outside of ETE. A few debug messages that trace the size of ETE and the indexes used for accessing ETE might help.

Comment: @Mr.Llama it is insane - after compiling with debug options... I no longer have segfault O.O I'll need to check the results, on first look they seems ok.

Comment: You may have to resort to `printf("made it here");`-style debugging.

Comment: `for (int i = ST; i <= FN; i++)` upper boundary looks suspect. Try throwing in a few `assert()`s

Comment: `if ((ETE[i] > ETE[i-1]) && (ETE[i] > ETE[i+1]) ... `  also looks suspect ([i-1] can be below and [i+1] can be above the actual array boundaries.)

Answer (score 3):

compile your code with debugging support and use GDB to run your code.  When the segfault happens you can look at the trace and see where the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling your program with debug information? This is enabled by running gcc with the `-g` option. If your program has debug info, valgrind will tell the line number where the invalid access occured. And with debug info you'll also have a much easier time using gdb.