# Don't see line numbers using Valgrind inside Ubuntu (Vagrant+Virtualbox)

Tags: c, ubuntu, valgrind, vagrant, line-numbers

I am currently reading and fallowing along the "[Learn C The Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/)"-book. On [exercise 4](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex4.html) I have to install [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). I first did this locally on my Macbook running Maverick, but I received a warning that Valgrind might not work 100%.

So now I tried it with Vagrant (using VirtualBox) with an Ubuntu 12.04 box. You can check out the exact Vagrantfile (setup) and the exercise files here on my [github repo](https://github.com/Ilyes512/LearnCTheHardWay).

**The problem:**
I don't  see the line numbers and instead I get something like `0x40052B`.

I compiled the files by doing the fallowing:

```
$ make clean # Just to be sure
$ make
$ valgrind --track-origins=yes ./ex4
```

I pasted the result to pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/QAAggdbY).

I found the fallowing 3 questions on SO that (partly) describes the same problem, but the answer's and there solutions didn't work for me:

- [Valgrind not showing line numbers in spite of -g flag (on Ubuntu 11.10/VirtualBox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321385/valgrind-not-showing-line-numbers-in-spite-of-g-flag-on-ubuntu-11-10-virtualbo)
- [How do you get Valgrind to show line errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797864/how-do-you-get-valgrind-to-show-line-errors/15224219#15224219)
- [Valgrind does not show line-numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130246/valgrind-does-not-show-line-numbers)

What I have tried sofar:

- Added `libc6-dbg`
- installed `gcc` and tried compiling with that instead of `cc`.
- added `--track-origins=yes` to the `valgrind`-command
- Added (and later removed) compiling with `-static` and `-oO` flags

So I am not sure where to go from here? I could try and install the latest (instead of v3.7) off `gcc` manually although that looked rather difficult.

**edit:**
@abligh answer seems to be right. I made this with kaleidoscope:
[image]
On the left side you see the result of: `valgrind --track-origins=yes ./ex4` and on the right side the result of `valgrind ./ex4`.

I guess I still need to learn allot about `c` and it's tools.

Comment: What options are passed to gcc when you compile your programs? Is `-g` in there?

Comment: Yes... Everything is inside my repo. You can checkout the Makefile [here](https://github.com/Ilyes512/LearnCTheHardWay/blob/master/Makefile), the vagrantfile and the rest of the c-files.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585305/valgrind-not-showing-line-numbers-in-spite-of-g-flag-and-track-origins-yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are just missing them in the output.

Here is some of your output (copied from Pastebin):

```
==16314==    by 0x40052B: main (ex4.c:9)
                                     ^^--- LINE NUMBER
==16314==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==16314==    at 0x4004F4: main (ex4.c:4)
                                     ^^--- LINE NUMBER
```

Though I think your invocation is wrong to check memory leaks. I wrote a very simple program to leak one item:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  void *leak;
  leak = malloc (1);
  printf ("Leaked %p\n", leak);
  exit (0);
}
```

and compiled it using your `Makefile`:

```
gcc -Wall -g    test.c   -o test
```

Running your command:

```
$ valgrind --track-origins=yes ./test
==26506== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==26506== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==26506== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==26506== Command: ./test
==26506== 
Leaked 0x51f2040
==26506== 
==26506== HEAP SUMMARY:
==26506==     in use at exit: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==26506==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 1 bytes allocated
==26506== 
==26506== LEAK SUMMARY:
==26506==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26506==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26506==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26506==    still reachable: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==26506==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26506== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==26506== 
==26506== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==26506== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

But invoking the way I normally invoke it:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./test
==26524== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==26524== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==26524== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==26524== Command: ./test
==26524== 
Leaked 0x51f2040
==26524== 
==26524== HEAP SUMMARY:
==26524==     in use at exit: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==26524==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 1 bytes allocated
==26524== 
==26524== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==26524==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26524==    by 0x40059C: main (test.c:8)
==26524== 
==26524== LEAK SUMMARY:
==26524==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26524==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26524==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26524==    still reachable: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==26524==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26524== 
==26524== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==26524== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Note the line numbers are again in brackets, e.g.

```
==26524==    by 0x40059C: main (test.c:8)
                                ^^^^^^^^ <- FILENAME AND LINE NUMBER
```

Comment: I think you are right! Damm, I thought those hexadecimal's are not supposed to be there. Thanks! I will accept you answer when I can. Edit: Ow, I see I can accept it right away ^^